# SpriteKit - Objective C - camera Constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am currently working a `spriteKit` 2D game using `Objective C`. It's a tile based game similar to superMario. I am having a problem with my Camera.

I added a camera that is following my player, but when the player gets closer to the edges of the scene, the camera goes out of bounds. Setting up the camera was easy.

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

//add Camera
mainCamera = [SKCameraNode node];
self.camera = mainCamera;
}
```

then in :

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {    
[super update: currentTime];   
mainCamera.position = avatar.position;  
}
```

However i need to add Constraints so that the camera stays within the container of the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Add a physics body to the camera, make it a rectangle the size of the scene.

Since you are doing your update of the camera in the beginning of the update, the physics engine will move the camera prior to being drawn.

make sure you set the restitution to 0 to avoid bouncing

Comment: BTW, doing it in the beginning means your camera is always 1 frame behind,  Instead what you want to do, is make your camera a child of your avatar, and on update always reset it to CGPointZero